# Dart : i can't POST data in HTTP Message Body using HttpRequest.send() method

Tags: rest, jquery, post, httprequest, dart

In my Rest server, i can't read the data contained in the HTTP Message Body when the call comme from script writing in Dart.

When calling the same webservice with ajax, there is no problem. In both case the data send with the URL (pcParamUrl=yopla) can be read in the server side.

i think the problem come from "processData: false" in ajax, i don't know how to set this key in HttpRequest Dart object.

I am trying to convert this ***ajax*** call (javascript) :

```dart
var url = "http://127.0.0.1:8980/TestDartService/rest/TestDartService/Test?pcParamUrl=yopla";
$.ajax({url: url,
    type: "POST",
    processData: false,
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify({ request: {pcParamBody: "yepYep"} }),
    success: function(data, status) { alert(data.response.pcRetour); },
    error: function(status) { alert("erreur"); }
});
```

to this one using Dart:

```dart
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
request.onReadyStateChange.listen((_) {
    if (request.readyState == HttpRequest.DONE && request.status == 200 || request.status == 0)) {
        print(request.responseText);
    }
});
var url = "http://127.0.0.1:8980/TestDartService/rest/TestDartService/Test?pcParamUrl=yopla";
request.open("POST", url, async: false);
request.setRequestHeader("content-Type", "application/json");
String jsonData = JSON.encode('{ request: { pcParamBody: "yepYep" } }'); // etc...
request.send(jsonData);
```

thanks for your help and sorry for my bad english

Comment: Recently I needed to make POST request using Dart, but I cannot send a POST data at all. Can you try again and see if that is working fine?

Comment: If you have a solution, can you explain them and post a comment in this question please ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25085152/dart-gae-why-a-post-method-send-from-dart-cant-be-evaluate-in-gae

Answer (score 1):

(moved from the Question:)

The problem is the format of the data being passed to `JSON.encode`; it should be an object; or you could skip the encoding altogether:

```dart
String jsonData = JSON.encode('{request: {pcParamBody: "yepYep"}}'); // BAD
String jsonData = JSON.encode({"request": {"pcParamBody": "yepYep"}}'); // GOOD
String jsonData = '{request: {pcParamBody: "yepYep"}}'; // ALSO GOOD
```