# DART & GAE : Why a POST method send from dart can't be evaluate in GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine, post, dart

I have a Dart code used to send an HttpRequest with a POST method to my GAE WepApp2 application. The dart code is executed in chromium and serve by Chrome dev editor. I add in my GAE code some headers to avoid the XHR error in the client side.

The dart code send the datas to my GAE app but I can't read the data with **self.request.POST.get("language"))** and the app never enter in **def post(self):** section but with **self.request.body** I can read the data.

Could you explain that and provide some correction to have a full POST compliant code?

dart:

```dart
void _saveData() {
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest(); // create a new XHR

    // add an event handler that is called when the request finishes
    request.onReadyStateChange.listen((_) {
      if (request.readyState == HttpRequest.DONE &&
          (request.status == 200 || request.status == 0)) {
        // data saved OK.
        print(request.responseText);
      }
    });

    // POST the data to the server
    var url = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/savedata";
    request.open("POST", url, async: false);

    String jsonData = JSON.encode({"language":"dart"});
    request.send(jsonData);
  }
```

GAE code in my handler:

```dart
  def savedata(self):
    logging.info("test")
    logging.info(self.request.body)
    logging.info(self.request.POST.get("language"))
    def post(self):
      logging.info("test 2")
      logging.info(self.request.POST.get("language"))

    self.response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "http://127.0.0.1:49981"
    self.response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Methods"] = "POST, GET, OPTIONS"
```

Comment: You are aware that the CORS request is preflight - it just checks if the request is allowed - after this CORS request the real request containing the data is done as a new (2nd) request?

Comment: Hi Gûnter, If I understand well your comment my 2 headers in GAE code is not very useful because the DART code is not serve by him.

Comment: No, this is necessary if you load the page from some localhost address and want to access your GAE server. I just want to make you aware of the fact that the browser actually does **two** requests instead of one. The first is only to check if the returned headers allow a CORS request and only after that, the request you made in your Dart code is executed. In the first request (I guess type `OPTIONS`) you only need to set the headers and be done, and in the second request you can process the received data.

Comment: I also try with app.yaml but chromium return always a CORS error. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig?hl=fr#Python_app_yaml_Static_file_handlers

Comment: If you get a CORS error can you try `"*"` instead of `"http://127.0.0.1:49981"`. What CORS error do you get?

Comment: I add in my app.yaml in the section handlers http_headers: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*" and I remove headers in the code. Now chromium return XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1:8080/savedata. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:49981' is therefore not allowed access. VM8535:1
Exception: NetworkError: Failed to load 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/savedata'.

Comment: `127.0.0.1:8080` is you local GAE dev server? Does your GAE return the headers only at `127.0.0.1:8080` or also on requests to `127.0.0.1:8080/savedata`?

Comment: With my previous modification in app.yaml if I stop and start the dev server I got an error: Unexpected attribute "http_headers" for mapping type script and the server not start.

Comment: Yes 127.0.0.1:8080 is my local GAE.
This is the header return by request on 127.0.0.1:8080 and 127.0.0.1:8080/savedata: 

Date: Fri, 01 Aug 2014 18:27:04 GMT
Server: Development/2.0
access-control-allow-methods: POST
content-type: application/json
access-control-allow-origin: *
cache-control: no-cache
access-control-allow-headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
Content-Length: 0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58512/discussion-between-olituks-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Dart, if you don't specify **request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")** in your HttpRequest, the data is considered by GAE like a bite stream and you can only read them with **self.request.body**

If you add the Content-Type header in Dart you need also to change the data formating. In my case I mimic a form sending with POST method so I change **String jsonData = JSON.encode({"language":"dart"});** by **String jsonData = "language=dart2";**

IN GAE python I can now read the data with **self.request.POST.get("language")**

If you need to send a JSON from DART to GAE, you can encode the string like this:

```dart
String jsonData = JSON.encode({"test":"valuetest1"});
String datas = "datas=$jsonData";
request.send(datas);
```

In GAE you can read the datas like this:

```dart
my_json = json.loads(self.request.POST.get("datas"))
logging.info(my_json["test"])
```

The complete code:

**Dart**

```dart
void _saveData2() {
    String url = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/savedata";
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest() 
      ..open("POST", url, async: true)
      ..setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
      ..responseType = "arraybuffer";

    String jsonData = JSON.encode({"test":"valuetest1"});
    String datas = "datas=$jsonData";
    request.send(datas);
  }
```

**GAE**

```python
class PageHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

  def savedata(self):

    self.response.headers.add_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'

    #logging.info(self.request)
    my_json = json.loads(self.request.POST.get("datas"))
    logging.info(my_json["test"])
```